# Session value returns null when checking whats stored

Tags: angular, typescript, session, ionic-framework

I am working on an ionic app, that i need to create a session, so when the user logins, i have his name stored, then i can check if the user really is logged in or not. To do so, i create a model class and a user class. My issue is that when i try to console log my value stored inside ionic it returns null values, here is an image explaining exactly the output:

[image]

I don't understand why is it logging like `'0: 'n', 1: 'o', 2: 'm', 3: 'e'`.
What I want to do is store the username inside my session and log at the same time.

Here's how i am doing this:

```
import { Storage } from "@ionic/storage";
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Usuario } from "./interface/usuario";

@Injectable()
export class Session {

    constructor(public storage: Storage){}

    create(usuario: Usuario) {
        this.storage.set('usuario', usuario);
    }

    get(): Promise<any> {
        return this.storage.get('usuario');
    }

    remove() {
        this.storage.remove('usuario');
    }

    exist() {
        this.get().then(res => {
            console.log('resultado >>> ', res);
            if(res) {
                console.log('resultado IF');
                return true;
            } else {
                console.log('resultado else');
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

My User/Usuario class:

```
import { Model } from './../models/model';

export class Usuario extends Model{
    nome: string;
    email: string;
    login: string;
    senha: string;
}
```

Model Class

```
import { Usuario } from './../interface/usuario'; 

export class Model{ 
    constructor(Usuario){ 
        Object.assign(this, Usuario); 
    } 
}
```

Where I retrieve what was stored inside my Usuario object and log it right after

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
  this.carregarPerfil();
  this.session.get()
    .then(res => {
      this.usuarioLogado = new Usuario(res);
      console.log('usuário logado  >>> ', this.usuarioLogado);
    });

  console.log(this.session.exist());

  this.session.remove();

  this.session.get()
    .then(res => {
      this.usuarioLogado = new Usuario(res);
      console.log('USUARIO LOGADO  >>> ', this.usuarioLogado);
    });

  console.log(this.session.exist());
}
```

EDIT: here's what happens when i console.log inside create, using storage.get

```
https://imgur.com/a/W2rQhd8

    create(usuario: Usuario) {
        this.storage.set('usuario', usuario);
        console.log('[TEST] VALUE BEING PASSED IS ', this.storage.get('usuario'));
    }
```

Comment: debug what object is passing in `create` during runtime! or post the `Model` class and how you are setting the object!

Comment: Please create a [Minimalist StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/react) replicating this issue.

Comment: @Ravikumar here's my model class: import { Usuario } from './../interface/usuario';
export class Model{
    constructor(Usuario){
        Object.assign(this, Usuario);
    }
}

Comment: @SiddAjmera pls post the how you are setting the object!

Comment: Sorry for the delay @SiddAjmera, here's the code https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-6jcigi?file=pages%2Flogin%2Flogin.ts

Comment: im assigning my Usuario class and passing it as an object inside object.assign inside my model class

Comment: @JohnRivers, your StackBlitz has some issues related to modules. Please consider fixing them first.

Comment: @SiddAjmera should be fixed now!

Comment: Still seeing those errors and also how do I navigate to LoginPage?

Comment: For some reason im getting this error: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[LoginPage -> Session]:
StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[LoginPage -> Session]:
NullInjectorError: No provider for Session!, when trying to push the login page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what's going on:

- In login.ts you have the following line: `this.usuario = new Usuario('nome');`
- Usuario inherits from Model.
- Model calls `object.assign()` using the parameter from the constructor to set its own parameters.
- A string is inherently an array.
- So by calling `object.assign(this, 'nome')` you are creating parameters corresponding to each index in the string with the value as each character.

Obviously you want to do something different on the line, such as passing `item` into the constructor.  However I think the object.assign business is asking for trouble and you should be much more explicit about the deserialization of your result.

```
export class Usuario {
    nome: string;
    email: string;
    login: string;
    senha: string;

    constructor(src: any) {
        if (src) {
            this.nome = src['nome'] || undefined;
            this.email = src['email'] || undefined;
            this.login = src['login'] || undefined;
            this.senha = src['senha'] || undefined;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the conext of src? my apologies but i dont understand exactly what your code does

Comment: src is the object you pass into the constructor.  When you call `this.usuarioLogado = new Usuario(res);` in your example, `res` will be `src`.

Comment: You are displaying the Promise object.  You need to do `this.storage.get('usuario').then(x => console.log(x))`